# PHP/MYSQL - Select option value not being sent?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code which should return all of the teams within a certain region. I have a database of football teams that contains tables for Teams and States. The teams table has a foreign key reference to a states table, and the states table has an attribute for regions (north, south, east, west).

I have the following html/php code on my main page:

```
<div>
  <form method="post" action="regions_filter.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Filter Teams By Region</legend>
        <select name="Region">
            <?php 
            if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT region FROM states"))){
                echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                }

            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }
            if(!$stmt->bind_result($region)){
                echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo '<option value=" ' . $region . ' "> ' . $region . '</option>\n';
            }
            $stmt->close();
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Run Filter"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Below is the regions_filter.php file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Teams By Region</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>School Name</td>
        <td>State Name</td>
        <td>State Capital</td>
        <td>State Population</td>
        <td>Region</td>
    </tr>
<?php
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT teams.school_name, states.name,       states.capital, states.population, states.region FROM teams
                            INNER JOIN states ON states.id = teams.state_id
                            WHERE states.region = ?"))){
echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!($stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['Region']))){
echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!$stmt->execute()){
echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli- >connect_error;
}
if(!$stmt->bind_result($school, $state, $capital, $population, $region)){
echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli- >connect_error;
}
while($stmt->fetch()){
 echo "<tr>\n<td>" . $school . "\n</td>\n<td>" . $state . "\n</td>\n<td>" .   $capital . "\n</td>\n</td>"
    . $population . "\n</td>\n<td>" . $region . "\n</td>\n</tr>";
}
$stmt->close();
?>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I go to run the filter on my main page, I am taken to the regions_filter.php page with no results. The only thing that shows up is the pre-coded html table at the top of the regions_filter.php page.
I believe the error is somewhere in the code snippet below. I have tried different variations with the option value but can't seem to crack it:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo '<option value=" ' . $region . ' "> ' . $region . '</option>\n';
            }
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RuchishParikh hmm that didn't seem to fix it, i'll keep playing with it

Comment: Do you get the form in the main page populated properly? can we see a sample of it?

Comment: That's it, check my answer, you have extra spaces in the region name in the <options>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error populating the regions select there is an extra white space before and after the region name. It should be like:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
   echo '<option value="' . $region . '">' . $region . '</option>\n';
}
```

Comment: YES! thank you so much! I had no idea that white space would cause this issue

Comment: When you run a query searching for region = " South " it won't match anything because " South " != "South" they are not the same string.

Comment: thanks that makes sense, I haven't been using php for very long so i've learned something new today

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the states.id on your where statement is not region id. If you are filtering $region as a parameter from the  tag to the select statement state.id = ? (state.id = $region) it will not give any results. because your are filtering via states.
*Note: This is just my first understanding on the above code*

I don't think you have any errors on this...it's just that you might be filtering the wrong attribute ^_^

Comment: you were right about that, I accidently copied over the old code...i've updated the correct code fragment where my select statement searches on WHERE states.region = ?

Comment: did it fix the problem? if not...let's try again ^_^

Comment: unfortunately no, gonna keep playing around with it

Comment: Try this
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT teams.school_name, states.name,       states.capital, states.population, states.region FROM teams
                            INNER JOIN states ON states.id = teams.state_id
                            WHERE states.region = '?' ")

Comment: since region is varchar I assume the where statement is looking for a string and you need to put ' ' like that to say that it is a string. if ? is a binder of $region like a variable it might be rendering states.region = east but to correct that it must render states.region = 'east' if region is a varchar or char data type

Comment: I thought that would solve the issue too when i tried that earlier...when I add the quotations around '?' i get this error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /nfs/stak/students/d/dejarnen/public_html/regions_filter.php on line 34
Bind failed: 0

Comment: On mysqli_prepare the markers can't be single-quoted

Comment: @NickD I tried it out from the link you gave from the live webpage I tried to filter via region and it works fine....When I filter South it shows all the south region tagged dat